# Why Autherize.net payment gateway is showing fatal error of create card

Tags: php, codeigniter, payment-gateway, expressionengine

I installed the subscription module in Expressionengine and after installing it I develop its template here it is :-

```
{exp:subs:subscribe register_member="yes" plan="abc" payment_method="authorize" return="/account/subscription/%SUBS_HASH%"}

<h1>Subscribe to: {subs:plan:label}</h1>
<p>
    Every <strong>{subs:plan:recurring_interval_count} {subs:plan:recurring_interval}</strong> {subs:plan:recurring_amount} {subs:plan:currency}
</p>
<hr>

{if subs:total_errors}
<ul class="errors">
    {subs:form_errors}
    <li>{subs:error}</li>
    {/subs:form_errors}
</ul>
{/if}

<h3>Credit Card</h3>

<label>Credit Card Number</label>
<input name="card_number" type="text" value="{subs:card_number}">

<label>Name on card</label>
<input name="card_name" type="text" value="{subs:card_name}">

<label>Expires</label>
<select name="card_exp_month">{subs:month_options}</select>
<select name="card_exp_year">{subs:year_options}</select>         

<label>Security Code</label>
<input name="card_cvc" type="text" value="{subs:card_cvc}" size="5">


<button type="submit">Subscribe</button>

{/exp:subs:subscribe}
```

But after feeling the required info like card no.,date,Security Code,Expiry date I am getting a Fatal error here it is

Fatal error: Call to a member function supportsCreateCard() on a non-object in /home/expresssoft/public_html/system/expressionengine/third_party/subs/src/Service/CardsService.php on line 16

My autherize.net account supports these cards=Visa, MasterCard, American Express, Discover, Diners Club, JCB

Comment: You could start by showing us some code from where you call `supportsCreateCard()` as that is where the error is most likely to be rather than in a page template

Comment: @RiggsFolly I got the solution.

Comment: If you got the solution you should, for the good of SO in general, post the solution so that others like yourself can benefit from it. I believe its even possible to accept your own answer thus gaining you some reputation points.

Comment: ...or delete the question.

Comment: *TO ALL* : anyone who want answer of this question please mention in comment now I will only give to those who want because no one gave me the answer so i will give him privately.

Comment: lets I give you hint i.e. *AIM* now lets prove who is more intelligent.

Answer (score 0):

payment_method="authorize" was wrong, You must have use payment_method="authorizenet_aim" or payment_method="authorizenet_cim". Right ?